# For what value of c is there no solution

Tags: linear-algebra

I'm given the following problem and cannot figure it out. Given the linear system of two equations below, for what value of $c$ are there no solutions to the linear system?

$$\begin{cases}x+2y=4\\cx+6y=1\end{cases}$$

My reasoning is that if they share the same slope then they are parallel lines and therefore there is no solution. The slope is $-1/2$. But, I get the answer wrong. What am I missing? Thank you.

Comment: If the slope of the second line is $-1/2$ it must be $3x+6y=1$. Is that consistent with the first equation?

Answer (score 1):

There are a few ways you could do this. The way you were thinking was fine: the two equations produce the lines

$$y=-\frac{1}{2}x+2 \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ y=-\frac{c}{6}x+\frac{1}{6}$$

For the lines to have the same slope,

$$-\frac{1}{2}=-\frac{c}{6}$$

which you can solve on your own.

---

Here's another way you could do it: if you were to multiply the first equation by $3$, for example, you would have the system

$$\begin{cases} 3x+6y=12 \\ cx+6y=1
\end{cases}$$

From here, you could solve the system of equations for $x$, which gives

$$x=\frac{11}{3-c}$$

Can you see which value of $c$ doesn't work?

Answer (score 0):

Lines are paralel to each other but not coincide so they must satisfy the condition

$$\frac{1}{c}=\frac{2}{6} \not= \frac{4}{1}$$ $2c=6$, $c=3$

There is no any intersection point for $c=3$

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**:

There is a very simple criterion for a non-homogeneous linear system to have solution:
the matrix of the left-hand side and the augmented matrix must have the same rank. Furthermore, this common rank is the codimension of the affine space of solutions.

Answer (score 0):

Your set of equation can be presented in matrix form as follows:
$$ \begin{bmatrix}1 & 2 \\c & 6 \end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix}x \\ y \end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}4 \\ 1 \end{bmatrix}$$

This is not solvable when the $\begin{bmatrix}1 & 2 \\c & 6 \end{bmatrix}$ in noninvertible. As you mention, it is when the two lines are parallel and make the matrix's rank lower than 2. This can be check from the determinant of the matrix. If it is not solvable
$$ det(\begin{bmatrix}1 & 2 \\c & 6 \end{bmatrix})=0 $$
which is,
$$ 6-2c=0 \\
c = 3 $$

Your answer is correct, maybe you did not explain how you get to the answer.

Comment: It must be  6=2c and c=3

Comment: thanks, yes I corrected it